# How do I detect a running WSL distro using C

Tags: linux, c, random

So I'm trying to implement a RNG on Windows and as part of creating the seed I'm checking for installed and currently active WSL distros to get some random bits from /dev/random.

Afaik there is no API in C that directly connects to the WSL Distro, so I'm running the `wslconfig /l /running` command from my C script, storing and parsing the output to check for running WSL distros, and if one is detected then fetch the bits from /dev/random.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int WSLGetEntropy(unsigned char* randBuf, size_t randBufSize) {
    wchar_t buffer[128];
    
    FILE* pipe = _wpopen(L"wslconfig /l /running", L"rb");
    if (!pipe) return 0;

    size_t bytesRead = fread(buffer, sizeof(wchar_t), sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(wchar_t), pipe);

    if (bytesRead == 0) {
        printf("No data received\n");
        _pclose(pipe);
        return 0;
    }

    /* Convert the wide character buffer to a regular C string */
    char* bufferStr = (char*) malloc(bytesRead + 1);
    if (bufferStr == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        return 0;
    }
    wcstombs(bufferStr, buffer, bytesRead);
    bufferStr[bytesRead] = '\0';
    /* parse the command output to get the name of any active wsl distro */

    char* start = strstr(bufferStr, "Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:\r\r\n");
    if (start == NULL) {
        free(bufferStr);
        _pclose(pipe);
        return 0;
    }

    start += 45;
    char* end = strstr(start, " (Default)");
    if (end == NULL) {
        free(bufferStr);
        _pclose(pipe);
        return 0;
    }

    size_t length = end - start;
    char* wslDistroName = (char*) malloc(length + 1);
    if (wslDistroName == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        free(bufferStr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    strncpy(wslDistroName, start, length);
    wslDistroName[length] = '\0';
    
    /* Get randBufSize bytes from /dev/random if a running WSL2 distro is detected */
    char *loc = malloc(12 + 17 + length + 1);
    strcpy(loc, "\\\\wsl.localhost\\");
    strcat(loc, wslDistroName);
    strcat(loc, "\\dev\\random");
    FILE *file = fopen(loc, "rb");

    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening random");
        return 0;
    }

    bytesRead = fread(randBuf, 1, randBufSize, file);

    if (bytesRead != randBufSize) {
        perror("Error reading from random");
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }

    fclose(file);
    free(wslDistroName);
    free(bufferStr);
    _pclose(pipe);
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    unsigned char buf[64];
    if (WSLGetEntropy(buf, 64)){
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) printf("%02x ", buf[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However the string parsing and indirectly running the command like this makes this very inefficient. Is there a better and faster method to achieve this? Speed and memory are very important factors for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

> However the string parsing and indirectly running the command like this makes this very inefficient. Is there a better and faster method to achieve this? Speed and memory are very important factors for my use case.

Then don't do that at all. *Any* of that. Your code is already running on an OS that has *its own* system-wide CSPRNG – **[BCryptGenRandom()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptgenrandom)** as part of the CNG cryptography module – that's available through direct C calls, without the need to call out into a whole separate virtual machine (and most likely, that's the slowest part – string parsing is likely lost in the noise compared to reaching out to a separate OS via 9P).

That's what OpenSSL, GnuTLS, and most other cryptography libraries use, and it should be enough to provide a seed for your RNG as well.

If your Windows version supports WSL, then it is also guaranteed to support CNG/BCrypt functions (introduced in Vista – although the older CAPI equivalent, [CryptGenRandom()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgenrandom), was actually added in XP).

Comment: So, I was kind of vague by saying I need it for a seed. I have a randomness pool that I'm adding entropy to periodically. And I'm trying to diversify my entropy sources. I am already using WIN32's next gen BCryptGenRandom() as well. Ig I could do without this but if there does exist a better method to read from /dev/random/ then why not implement it.

Comment: But it doesn't really diversify much, as it's ultimately running in a virtual machine (with no access to physical hardware) on the same host – the VM itself has no good sources for its own randomness pool except for either the same RDRAND/RDSEED CPU instruction that you can already call directly, or possibly from the host via Hyper-V (sort of like how KVM has virtio-rand). All you have is an illusion of diversification.

Comment: Hmm that's a good point then. I already used RDSEED. I didn't know that it could be the major source of randomness for the WSL kernel.

Comment: It's one of the few good sources VMs have *at all*. Before RDSEED and/or virtio-rnd, it could sometimes take several minutes for the Linux CRNG to initialize, it was definitely not what you would have wanted to use as an additional source. But that's also the case in general – a VM's CRNG will never have a better seed source than the host itself already has. (For that matter, Windows seeds its CRNG using RDSEED as well.)